# FileNotFoundException while running SolrCloud on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, apache-zookeeper

I have a Solr 4.2.0 server which is running under the Tomcat 7.0 container. I'm trying to wire it with my external zookeeper (actually, it doesn't work with the embdedded zookeeper too).

I tried this java opts:

```
-Dbootstrap_confdir=./solr/collection1/conf 
-Dcollection.configName=myconf
-DzkRun
-DnumShards=2
```

for running the embedded zookeeper.

And also this java opts:

```
-Dbootstrap_confdir=./solr/collection1/conf 
-Dcollection.configName=myconf
-DzkHost=localhost:2181
-DnumShards=2
```

For connecting to external zookeeper

In both cases I continue to get the same exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '.\solr\collection1\conf \admin-extra.html' does not exist
```

But the problem is that file admin-extra.html exists and it's right here. And I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: have you tried absolute path?

Comment: are you certain your working directory is where you think it is?

Comment: Yes, with absolute path it looks like  File 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\solr\collection1\conf \admin-extra.html' does not exist

Comment: It can be just a typo while you wrote it but in the Exception, conf directory has a white space afterwards, that could be the problem. You could define bootstrap_confdir using ""

Comment: That's exactly what happened, thanks, i'm an idiot)

Comment: Don't worry, it happens. Glad I could help, I posted as answer so your question isn't left unanswered

Answer (score 1):

From your exception it seems your path has a white space after the *config* directory.
Try to define your **bootstrap_configdir** between "", like:

```
-Dbootstrap_confdir="./solr/collection1/conf"
```